# how to store number in double digit format?

Tags: c#, sql, database, digit

I have 100 textboxes in 00 to 99 manners in form. I want to store first 0 to 9 in double digit format like 00, 01, 02, .... 09. How can i store it in sql database in that format without making it a string. I am doing project in c#.

Comment: Why would you want to store it like that ? If they are not string values ? If you want them to display like that at UI then do the formatting at UI.

Comment: How do you insert your row to database, plz add your code.

Comment: @Coder of Code in textboxes user will enter their lucky number it could be  numbers not string.

Comment: @shA.t using sql insert command

Comment: Ok!, but in my answer you can see `insert` statement, and use it.

Comment: Ok Then you can save the values as int in database and when you are going to show them use the `string format` function to show them on UI. And if there leading number of zeros are going to be different then save that data as the `varchar(n)` in database.

Comment: @shA.t I can not give you code becasue it is in my home computer. right now i am in my office, sorry

Comment: @CoderofCode if i save it as varchar(n) then if next time i will use that field i have to parse it to int or it will behave like int?

Comment: You have to parse to int to do the integer operations. But if the leading zeros matters to  you and if they are going to be different number in digits then only try this approach other wise the if the number of digits are fixed then save it as int. And when need apply the `Padding` with the `0` to int value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have those values in that format just in your table;
You need to run a query to insert a new row or update a valid row;

```
string query = string.format("Insert Into <table name> Values (list of values)", int value(s));
```

or

```
string query = string.format("UPDATE <table name> Set (list of '<field name> = <value>'s)", int value(s));
```

You need just use `{0:00}` instead of `{0}` in your query string.

If you use `sqlCommand` at setting parameters use it in this way `= string("{0:00}", int value)`

> Note: all codes are sample, you need to generate your own codes.

If you need to store your value with format you should use one of `char` data-types in your table.

Comment: The string formatting will not work. Even you send the `001` to database with the column type of `int` then it will automatically save it as `1`.

Comment: As your question about `store` it, you mean where do you want to store it like that format ?

Comment: And not me but OP wants that format to store in int datatype column. Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If your filed is "int", I think it will be not possible. As 09 is 9 in integer. As per thumb rule of integer the leading ZERO have no value.

But you can always SELECT with formatting OR else use "varchar" type to store it as you need.

Hope I am clear enough..!!